# How do hackers hack into private network device?

Tags: network, access-control, internet

[image]

As a picture show above, how do hackers use PC0 to hack into PC1? They are in different private network. As far as I know, we can use VPN to communicate two different private networks, so do hackers use similar VPN technique to hack in?

Comment: I googled your title and got tons of hits explaining this.